# How to color symbols by data in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo

In MapInfo 10.0, how can I quickly colorize point symbols according to a field in the data table, without creating a new map? My data is just longitude, latitude and time, and I'd like to colorize the points according to the time field. This seems really basic but I can't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what i understand from your question is that you want to create points thematic,changes both symbol size and color.

you can do it as :

1.Map > Create Thematic Map

2.Select Point Ranges Default from template

3.Click Next and select a table and a field.

4.Select your Ranges...

The result will be sth. like this. you can more info [here](http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/c5f0c7263940a53d8525669b00568e6b/55b156970f50e3f98525713e005d202f?OpenDocument).

.

[image: thematic map]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I guess there's no easier way to do it? I'm debugging some code and it takes lots of clicks to create a new thematic map every time the data file changes.

Comment: I mean, can I make the symbol color depend on data in the current map, and for example quickly try colorizing it according to different fields, without creating a new map every time?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is the time field specifically you are having trouble with, I would suggest following the instructions at http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/10/MapInfoProfessionalUserGuide.pdf on page 175.

Specifically, you need to explicitly convert your data type to "Time/Date" in "Table Maintenance" and the text needs to be in the following format:

- `Date: yyyyMMdd`
- `Time: HHmmssfff`
- `DateTime: yyyyMMddHHmmssfff`